# How to get a value on event xxforms-value-changed?

Tags: orbeon

I would like to get the value and the name of the element(or ID) when a value has changed in 
fr-form-instance? I've added the followling in "fr-form-modal" :

```
<xforms:model id="fr-form-model">

                  ...
                  ...

    <xforms:action ev:event="xxforms-value-changed" ev:observer="fr-form-instance"> 
          <xxforms:variable name="changed-value" select="."/>//doesn't work
          //get name(or id) if possible
    </xforms:action>

                  ...
                  ...

</xforms:model>
```

The variable $changed-value is empty. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the `xxforms-value-changed` event does not provide useful event context information. So as things stand, this event does not allow you to retrieve the element or attribute that has change. I have [committed a change](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/64eb704a4f620e5e4ece56cb01fcde38497ec0a4) to support this.

In the meanwhile, you could instead listen to `xforms-value-changed` events in the UI, for example on an outer `<xforms:group>`. This will work for nodes that have controls bound to them.

Answer (score 2):

As ebruchez said you can use `<xforms:group>` in the body and observe the events. Below sample works.

```
    <xhtml:html>
    <xforms:model>
        ..
        ..
        ..

        <xforms:action ev:observer="all-fields"  ev:event="xforms-value-changed"> //you can list as many events as you wish to observe for the fields inside "all-fields" group.
            <xforms:message level="modal" value="event('xxforms:binding')" /> //This will show you the value which has got changed.
        </xforms:action>


    </xforms:model>

    <xhtml:body>
        <xforms:group id="all-fields">
            ...
            ...
            ...

        </xforms:group>
    </xhtml:body>
</xhtml:html>
```

Reference: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-events